# Combine 3 tables in this linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following domain entity class structures, minimized for ease of read.

```
public partial class Student
{
    public virtual ICollection<StudentUser> StudentUsers { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefaultStudent { get; set }
    ....
}

public partial class StudentUser
{
   public virtual ICollection<StudentUserRole> StudentUsers { get; set; }
   public bool IsDefaultStudentRole { get; set }
   public int? SectionId { get; set; }
   public virtual Section Section { get; set; }
   ....
}

public class StudentUserRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimaryStudentRole { get; set }
}

public class Section
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SectionCode { get; set; }
}
```

Now, given a `Student` instance, I need to find out the `SectionCode` of the `StudentUser` for which `IsDefaultStudent=true` and for that `StudentUser`, one of the `StudentUserRole`, set
`IsPrimaryStudentRole=true`.

Note, as per functionality only one such `StudentUser` under a `Student` can exist.

And we need to find out the `SectionCode` of that `StudentUser`.

I can do it by separate queries, but can you please help me do it in one query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `context.Student.First(s => s.IsDefaultStudent)?.StudentUsers.Where(su => su.IsDefaultStudentRole)?.Select(su => new { su.Section.SectionCode, su.StudentUsers.First(sur => sur.IsPrimaryStudentRole) } ).First()` or something like that

Comment: Why not `public virtual ICollection<StudentUserRole> StudentUserRoles { get; set; }` ?

Answer (score 0):

This one did the trick for me.

```
var primaryStudentUser = context.Student.StudentUsers.FirstOrDefault(su => su.IsDefaultStudentRole && su.StudentUserRoles.Any(sur => sur.IsPrimaryStudentRole));
```

Comment: It doesn't set anything?